# Examples of the time-dependent linear wave equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, textbook-recommendation, linear-pde, hyperbolic-pde, wave-equation

I am looking for examples of the non-autonomous linear wave equation that have some relevant applications.

What articles and sources (maybe, some catalogue like *Handbook of Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations*) may I refer to?

Comment: I would think that you need nonlinearity for interesting/nontrivial dynamics.

Comment: The wave equation on any non-stationary Lorentzian spacetime (that is, $\square_g u = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|\det g|}} \partial_i g^{ij} \sqrt{|\det g|} \partial_j u = 0$ for a Lorentzian metric $g_{ij}$) is an example. You can read about the (abstract) theory of such equations, for instance, in this [book](http://arxiv.org/abs/0806.1036). If you are looking for a list of interesting Lorentzian manifolds, you may want to take a look at this [book](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511535185).

Answer (score 1):

If the time dependence of the potentials is periodic in time, then one enters the field of [Floquet wave equations,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory) which is a very active field of study with many real-world and even practical applications. (A textbook is [Floquet Theory for Partial Differential Equations.](https://books.google.nl/books?id=NTUDCAAAQBAJ))

The recent interest focuses on topological aspects of these driven systems, under the name of "Floquet Topological Insulators". Here is a [review article,](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.5623) and here is an [online talk.](https://ocw.tudelft.nl/course-lectures/2-maxwells-equations-and-magnetic-circuits-2/) A specific application to the periodically driven Dirac equation is [here.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.09718)